# Select range between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need query to select value between to columns but one columns have same value 
For example :

```
12  1
12  2
12  3  ------
12  4
12  5
13  1
13  2
13  3
13  4  ------
13  5
```

i need range to 12 | 3 to 13 | 4

```
select * from table1 where
((a >=  '12' and B >= 2) and (a <=  '13' and b <=5))
```

so the 13 1 is missing :( i have no idea for this query

Comment: So are your values in the table numeric or text?  [Demo](https://rextester.com/HSFB90524)

Comment: So are 12,3 and 13,4 desired to be inlcuded or just 12,4-13,3?

Comment: from 12 ,3 to 13,4  ???

Comment: what the reqired output!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic is:

```
where (a > 12 and a < 13) or
      (a = 12 and b >= 3) or
      (a = 13 and b <= 4)
```

Of course, you can also express this more simply using tuples:

```
where (a, b) >= (12, 3) and
      (a, b) <= (13, 4)
```

Comment: tuples seems easiest; but the values need to change or we need to use just > and <  May need to adjust to (12,3) and (13,4)

Comment: @simon . . . They are both fixed.

Answer (score 1):

this will surely work:

```
select * from Table1 where 
(a=12 and b>=3) or(a=13 and b<=4);
```

check this up :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c94ab/6

Comment: I think you want `b<=3` to be `B>=3`

Comment: @xQbert i have corrected the user wants rows from 3 to 9

Answer (score 0):

I think that works:

select *  from Test 
where (a = 12 and b > 2) or (a = 13 and b < 5);